# display removed value from string

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code

```
var inputText = document.getElementById("textValue").value;
var trimmedText = inputText.substr(1, inputText.length);
document.getElementById("textValue").value = trimmedText;
var subStr = trimmedText.substr(0, 1);
alert(subStr);
```

The above code is inside an `OnClick` which removes the first character from `input` value and updates the `input` value with the new trimmed string. What I'm trying to achieve it to store that trimmed character in a variable. Suppose I type `ABCD` in the alert function I get `BCD`. However I want to alert `A` does anyone know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `inputText.substr(0, 1)` would contain the first character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the first character before removing it:

```
var inputText = document.getElementById("textValue").value;
var firstChar = inputText.substr(0, 1);
var trimmedText = inputText.substr(1, inputText.length);
document.getElementById("textValue").value = trimmedText;
alert(firstChar);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3rvuvt6/1/)

Comment: Duh! I can't believe I didn't think of this :/ I feel a little stupid I think I need a break.. Thanks for this, works perfectly. I will accept the answer when time limit is up

Comment: It's always usefull to take a break `:)`